# Are direct summands of an Abelian group always direct summands together?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, direct-sum

Suppose that $G$ is an Abelian group and $A$ and $B$ are both direct summands of $G$, i.e. there exist subgroups $C$ and $D$ such that $G=A\oplus C = B\oplus D$.  Then my question is, under what conditions is $A\oplus B$ a direct summand of $G$?  Does it suffice that $A\cap B = 0$, and if not what more is required?

Comment: No $A \cap B = \{0\}$ is not sufficient. For example, let $G = C_4 \oplus C_2$, where the summands have generators $a$ and $b$, and let $A$ and $B$ be the subgroups of order $2$ generated by $b$ and $2a+b$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Then what more is required?  In any case I'm interested in the case when $G$ is infinite.

Comment: For an infinite example, let $G = {\mathbb Z} \oplus {\mathbb Z}$ with $A = \langle (0,1) \rangle$, $B = \langle (2,1) \rangle$.

Comment: OK, so what further conditions do we need to add to ensure that $A\oplus B$ is a direct summand?